# How do I get SmartGit to only show me one repository at a time?

Tags: smartgit

I'm looking for a TortoiseSvn replacement for Linux and not having much joy. I have SmartGit installed but it has this really undesirable behaviour whereby it remembers every repository I've ever opened, and whenever I open a specific repository using the --open  command it shows me every repository I've ever opened all at the same time.

All the other directories I've opened are listed in a 'Repositories' window on the left, and if I accidentally click on one of them I end up with this ridiculous situation where the SmartGit window titlebar show the name of a repository that is different from the one it's actually showing me.

I can't actually think of an occasion where I would need to manipulate multiple repositories simultaneously so this entire feature strikes me as misguided and deeply unhelpful. Is there any way I can disable it so that when I use SmartGit to open a specific repository it just shows me the repository I told it to open?

Comment: Most probably SmartGit stores the list of previously opened repositories in `~/.smartgit`. You can write a simple bash script, that will clear the list of repositories and then run SmartGit. Run this script instead of `smartgit --open` and you should be fine.

Comment: There is a tonne of stuff in there. A few things do look like a repository list and while I could try to create some kind of script that cleared it every time I opened SmartGit I would be concerned that I'd be deleting stuff that I don't remotely understand. That approach might also stop working whenever I update SmartGit. For now I've just closed the repository window and SmartGit remembers that I've closed it and never shows it to me. Pretty weak I know.